# Regex IsMatch taking too long to execute

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have one strange issue on my .NET project with RegEx. Please, see C# code below:

```
const string PATTERN = @"^[a-zA-Z]([-\s\.a-zA-Z]*('(?!'))?[-\s\.a-zA-Z]*)*$";
const string VALUE = "Ingebrigtsen Myre (Øvre)";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(PATTERN);
if (!regex.IsMatch(VALUE)) // <--- Infinite loop here
     return string.Empty;
// Some other code
```

I use this pattern to validate all types of names (fist names, last names, middle names, etc.). Value is a parameter, but I provided it as a constant above, because issue is not reproduced often - only with special symbols: *, (, ), etc. (sorry, but I don't have the full list of these symbols).

Can you help me to fix this infinite loop? Thanks for any help.

Added: this code is placed on the very base level of project and I don't want to do any refactoring there - I just want to have quick fix for this issue.

Added 2: I do know that it technically is not a loop - I meant that "regex.IsMatch(VALUE)" never ends. I waited for about an hour and it was still executing.

Comment: Nested quantifiers like `(x*)*` can cause big performance problems. Why don't you explain what you're trying to accomplish, and perhaps we can suggest a better way.

Comment: Do you mean that the `IsMatch` methods is taking too long to complete? There is no loop in your code so you can't really have an infinite loop. Chances are that the regex is taking a really long time to fully analyze the code due to all the 0 or more matches that it might need to find permutations for...

Comment: You should take a look at this post about names before you try and enforce validation on them: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 3):

Your non-trivial regex: `^[a-zA-Z]([-\s\.a-zA-Z]*('(?!'))?[-\s\.a-zA-Z]*)*$`, is better written with comments in free-spacing mode like so:

```cs
Regex re_orig = new Regex(@"
    ^                 # Anchor to start of string.
    [a-zA-Z]          # First char must be letter.
    (                 # $1: Zero or more additional parts.
      [-\s\.a-zA-Z]*  # Zero or more valid name chars.
      (               # $2: optional quote.
        '             # Allow quote but only
        (?!')         # if not followed by quote.
      )?              # End $2: optional quote.
      [-\s\.a-zA-Z]*  # Zero or more valid name chars.
    )*                # End $1: Zero or more additional parts.
    $                 # Anchor to end of string.
    ",RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

In English, this regex essentially says: *"Match a string that begins with an alpha letter `[a-zA-Z]` followed by zero or more alpha letters, whitespaces, periods, hyphens or single quotes, but each single quote may not be immediately followed by another single quote."*

Note that your above regex allows oddball names such as: `"ABC---...'... -.-.XYZ  "` which may or may not be what you need. It also allows multi-line input and strings that end with whitespace.

The "infinite loop" problem with the above regex is that [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) occurs when this regex is applied to a long invalid input which contains two single quotes in a row. Here is an equivalent pattern which matches (and fails to match) the exact same strings, but does not experience catastrophic backtracking:

```cs
Regex re_fixed = new Regex(@"
    ^                # Anchor to start of string.
    [a-zA-Z]         # First char must be letter.
    [-\s.a-zA-Z]*    # Zero or more valid name chars.
    (?:              # Zero or more isolated single quotes.
      '              # Allow single quote but only
      (?!')          # if not followed by single quote.
      [-\s.a-zA-Z]*  # Zero or more valid name chars.
    )*               # Zero or more isolated single quotes.
    $                # Anchor to end of string.
    ",RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

And here it is in short form in your code context:

```cs
const string PATTERN = @"^[a-zA-Z][-\s.a-zA-Z]*(?:'(?!')[-\s.a-zA-Z]*)*$";
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this part of your regex:

```
( [-\s\.a-zA-Z]* ('(?!'))? [-\s\.a-zA-Z]* )*$
^              ^         ^              ^  ^ 
|              |         |              |  |
|              |         |              |  This group repeats any number of times
|              |         |              charclass repeats any number of times
|              |         This group is optional
|              This character class also repeats any number of times
Outer group (repeated, as seen above)
```

That means that as soon as your input string contains a character that's not in the character class (like the brackets and non-ASCII letter in your example), the preceding characters will be tried in a lot of permutations whose number increases exponentially with the length of the string.

To avoid that (and to allow a faster failure of the regex, use [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html):

```
const string PATTERN = @"^[a-zA-Z](?>(?>[-\s\.a-zA-Z]*)(?>'(?!'))?(?>[-\s\.a-zA-Z])*)*$";
```

Comment: Won't simply adding a single plus sign fix it too? (See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149800/regex-ismatch-taking-too-long-to-execute/18151761#18151761))

Answer (score 0):

You've got an "any number of any number" here:

```
 ...[-\s\.a-zA-Z]*)*
```

and because your input *doesn't* match, the engine backtracks to try all permutations of dividing the input up, and the number of attempts grows exponentially with the length of the input.

You can fix it simply by adding a "+" to make a [*possessive quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), which once consumed will *not* backtrack to find other combinations:

```
const string PATTERN = @"^[a-zA-Z]([-\s\.a-zA-Z]*('(?!'))?[-\s\.a-zA-Z]*+)*$";
                                                                        ^-- added + here
```

You can see a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/N4g2anBb4p) (on rubular) demonstrating that adding the plus fixed the loop problem, and still matches input that doesn't have the odd characters.

Comment: Unfortunately, .NET doesn't support possessive quantifiers.

Comment: @tim aaaagggh! I thought I had you :) oh well, good to learn.